# Class has two properties of the same name. Why does this happen?

Tags: java, jersey

I implemented a Java web service (JAX-RS API Jersey implementation). There is an entity:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class TestPhoto extends Photo {
    public enum Type {
        BEFORE, AFTER, ADDON
    }

    private User author;
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
    private LocalDateTime createdTime;
    private Type type;

    public TestPhoto() {
        super();
    }

    public TestPhoto(Long id, String key, String path, User author, LocalDateTime createdTime, Type type) {
        super(id, key, path);
        this.author = author;
        this.createdTime = createdTime;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public User getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(User author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedTime() {
        return createdTime;
    }

    public void setCreatedTime(LocalDateTime createdTime) {
        this.createdTime = createdTime;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

When I am trying to retrieve a list of such entities, I get an error:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 8 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "createdTime"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.time.LocalDateTime com.test.TestPhoto.getCreatedTime()
        at com.test.TestPhoto
        at public java.util.List com.test.TestAccount.getAddonPhotos()
        at com.test.TestAccount
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.time.LocalDateTime com.test.TestPhoto.createdTime
        at com.test.TestPhoto
        at public java.util.List com.test.TestAccount.getAddonPhotos()
        at com.test.TestAccount
```

I know how to fix this. For instance, I could rename private fields and add `_` as a prefix. Or I could add a `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` annotation to a field.
I see also, that there is something wrong with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)` annotation. If comment it out everything works fine. But that part of functionality won't work in this case.

What I am trying to understand is why this happened in the first place. The code worked perfectly fine and then just stopped and started throwing such exceptions. Should this code have worked in the first place? Or is it completely wrong?

Comment: Does `Photo` also have an annotated `createdTime`? You would not have to declare it in this class if that is the case.

Comment: I think the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` is automatically adding the field to the list or properties. Try adding it on the getter instead (which is by default a property)

Comment: @Zircon No, photo does not have this property.

Comment: @peeskillet Makes sense. Will try that!